# NettyApplicationEngine is given but ApplicationEngine is expected

Tags: ktor

Hey I maked my Projekt on [the Ktor Project Creator](https://start.ktor.com) but i got Errors that in `embeddedServer()` an `ApplicationEngine` is expectet but an `NettyApplicationEngine` is given:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine.Configuration
Found:
io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.Configuration
```

[But i got unresolved errors too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oJKy.png) by `install{}` inside of the `embeddedServer{}` (and bcs that i think `jwt` is an unresolved reference too)

Does anyone know how to fix this error (or the errors)

[Here can you see the whole thing in one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/276eB.png)

Comment: This is most likely a problem in the Kotlin plugin https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19504. As a workaround, you can downgrade it as suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19504#focus=Comments-27-5150305.0-0

Comment: thanks that was realy usefull

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh sry i thought a pic of the whole code is enough

Comment: To reproduce the issue, just follow the steps on the ktor website: https://ktor.io/docs/intellij-idea.html#create_ktor_project